# Can artificial neural networks work with mathematical sets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I know that using neural networks for anything text-related is difficult as they have problems with non-numerical input data. 
But I'm not sure about mathematical sets. And sets of sets.

Like [0, 1, 2] and [3, 4, 5] or [[0, 1], [2, 3]] and [[4, 5], [6, 7]]

It should be possible to compute distances between these by computing the distances between all corresponding elements, right? I can't really find any information on that and don't want to start using neural networks without being sure.

(Googling anything with 'set' just isn't promising because all you get as result is the term 'data set'..)

EDIT:

First: The assignment specifically asks for a neural network, so I can't use k-means or any other clustering methods.

So the original question wasn't really addressing the actual problem. I don't have to think of a distance metric but of a way to add the sets to the activation function and for that of how to map them to a single value. But, regarding the distance metric, I'm actually not really sure at what point of the neural network I need it.. I guess that's a basic comprehension problem.

I will just write down some thoughts now.

The thing that confuses me is standardization of categories. Having three categories 'red', 'green' and 'blue' you can map them to numbers 1 to 3, but that would mean that 'red' would have a larger distance to 'blue' than 'green' does and that's not the case. So the categories are encoded as (1, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1) which gives them all the same distance.

So it must be possible to add these to the activation function somehow. I could imagine that they are interpreted as binary numbers, so that (1,0,0)=100=4, (0,1,0)=010=2 and (0,0,1)=001=1. That would be a distinct mapping. But numbers 1 to 3 are distinct to, so as mentioned above, the distance metric must be necessary at some point.

So the problem still is how to map a set to a single value. I can do that right before I add it to the function, so I don't have to choose a mapping that also maintains a logical distance between the sets because when getting to the point of applying the distance metric I can still apply it to the original sets and don't have to use the mapped value. Is that correct? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Is computing the distance between sets the *goal*?  Because there are a number of ways to do that, depending on how you define it, but once you've defined your distance metric, there's no need for machine learning; you can just compute it directly.  If that isn't the goal, what is?  There's almost certainly a way to encode the data (and contrary to what you've heard, it's pretty straightforward to encode textual data as well), but it'll depend on the problem description.

Comment: Well, clustering is the goal.. I guess my problem actually is the activation function. I somehow need to map the sets to simple values that I can add to the calculation, right? Or is there an activation function that can handle sets as part of the input vector? 

Or should I change the format of the input vector right at the beginning? 
So that (4, 5.2, [1, 0]) becomes (4, 5.2, 1, 0)? It doesn't seem right to give the set more importance like that..

I'm sorry for these basic questions but I'm totally new to this and can't find a satisfying answer.

Comment: You need to find some way of mapping your input onto a vector if you want to use a neural net.  Whether that particular way of doing it is ideal depends on how important it is to distinguish between {{1,0}} and {1,0}.  I think it would help if you edited the question to give more details on exactly what the sets represent, and why you're clustering them. Maybe some examples of the sort of sets that you would like to be clustered together.  Is `{0,1,2}` more similar to `{0,1}` or to `{{0},{1},{2}}`, for instance? Once we have that sort of information, we can give advice on how to (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) create either a mapping to an input vector (so you can use a neural network) or a formal distance metric (so you can use another clustering algorithm like K-means or hierarchical clustering).  No need to apologize for basic questions as long as you've tried to research it on your own. (It may not be as basic a question as you think, anyway.  Finding good encodings can sometimes be tricky even with experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Neural nets, in general, have no such problem.  Image recognition and language translation are well within their domains.  What you *do* need is the metrics and manipulations to relate your inputs to the ground truth in a well-ordered fashion -- which your distance metric will do quite nicely.

Go right ahead and build your neural network.  Supply it with the appropriate distance function, and let it train away.  Do make sure to put in some tracking instrumentation (e.g. print statements) to trace the operation for a few iterations before you turn it entirely loose.